# ContinuedFraction: different result with different representation of argument

Tags: bugs, numerics, continued-fractions

Why if I write:

```
In[7]:= ContinuedFraction[3.15]  

FromContinuedFraction[%]  

N[%]
```

I get:

```
Out[7]= {3, 6, 1}

Out[8]= 22/7

Out[9]= 3.14286
```

While if I write:

```
In[10]:= ContinuedFraction[315/100]

FromContinuedFraction[%]

N[%]
```

I get the right values:

```
Out[10]= {3, 6, 1, 2}

Out[11]= 63/20

Out[12]= 3.15
```

Somebody could help me on understanding?

Comment: Nothing wrong in what you did. That approximated one does appear to be incorrect.

Comment: Since this has returned to the front page, so to speak, I will note that I filed a bug report for it.